# Is there a formula to count the number of sets in a power set that have given pairs of elements?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider X = `P({1 2 3 4})` i.e. power set of a set of 4 numbers.

There are 4 sets containing the elements {1 2}:

```
{1 2 3 4}
{1 2 3}
{1 2 4}
{1 2}
```

There are 6 sets containing the elements {1 2} OR {1 3}:

```
{1 2 3 4}
{1 2 3}
{1 2 4}
{1 3 4}
{1 2}
{1 3}
```

Is there a formula to calculate this? Just the count of such sets is sufficient but a way to get the sets is nice too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ that contain one of two pairs $\{a,b\}$ or $\{c,d\}$ this can be counted as $$n_1 + n_2 - n_{1 \land 2}$$

where I denote by $n_1$ the number of subsets that contain the first pair, $n_2$ the number of subsets that contain the second pair, and by $n_{1 \land 2}$ the number of sets that contain both.

It's easy to see that $n_1 = n_2 = 2^{n-2}$ as one pair must be in the subset and all other points have a two-way choice of being in the set of not. 
Suppose $|\{a,b\} \cup \{c,d\}|=k$, ($k=3$ if the pairs overlap, $k=4$ of they don't), then a similar argument gives $n_{1 \land 2}=2^{n-k}$. So the number you want is

$$2^{n-1} - 2^{n-|\{a,b\} \cup \{c,d\}|} $$

which in your case, where $n=4$ and $\{1,2,3\}$ is the union comes down to $2^3 - 2^{1} = 6$ as we'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

Given a set $X$ of $n$ elements we have $|2^X|=2^n$. To count the number of subsets containing the given $k\le n$ elements exclude them from the set and count the subsets of the remaining set to get $2^{n-k}$.